# problem in posting data in json from iPhone to MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm a newbie to iPhone Development. Following is the to post data in json from iPhone to MySQL. Data seems to be posted from iPhone but problems occur while posting.

```
**- (IBAction) btnPostDataPressed   : (id) sender {

    NSURL *objUrl = [NSURL URLWithString : @"http://localhost/test_questionnaire/update.php"] ;
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL : objUrl] ;

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod : @"POST"];

    [theRequest setValue : @"application/json"
      forHTTPHeaderField : @"Content-Type"];

    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];

    //NSData *myData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"nasir here"];
    //[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"nasir here"];


    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:stringData forKey:@"code"];
    NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];

    NSString *strHttpBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", jsonString];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[strHttpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    textView.text = @"data successfully posted!!!";
}**
```

Also, I've tried with the lines commented out above but still problems remain.

Hoping for favorable response. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of problems occur? Does anything show up on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You cant't post against `localhost` as in that case it's your phone.

Use the IP of the server your PHP/MySQL script is running on, if you don't have local name resolution available

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Well, page is called but data isn't posted. Would you please further guide?